# How to activate menu item with image based on steps using php, jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a journal submission system. Previous and next buttons navigate each and every section. I want to display an image automatically before a menu item when I click the next button. How can I do this? I want it to look like this in the image.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code that you are working in and what is not working/what are you trying to achieve? Now we have nowhere to go on from. The idea here is just to check which step you are at currently and insert an image?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your code to help you in better way, but I guess you mean that you want to marked as active link the current step into the process, if you are using php and jQuery, probably you can use the URL to know where are you exactly, eg:

with pure Javascript you can get the pathname part of the URL just like this

```
window.location.pathname
```

so imagine you have this list of steps

```
<ul>
  <li class="steplist" data-step="step=1">
    <a>Step 1</a>
  </li>

  <li class="steplist" data-step="step=2">
    <a>Step 2</a>
  </li>

  <li class="steplist" data-step="step=3">
    <a>Step 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

so now with jQuery you can make a function that execute when page load, like so:

```
function markCurrentStep() {
    var currentStep = window.location.pathname;
    var hasStep = currentStep.match(/step=(\d+)/);
    if (hasStep && hasStep[1]) {
        currentStep = hasStep[1]; // we get the step number eg: step=12 <- we get only 12
        var currentStepList = $(".steplist").find("[data-step='" + currentStep + "']");
        // make sure you find the element that match with the step based on data step attribute
        if (currentStepList && currentStepList.length > 0) {
            var imgMarker = $("<img src='URL_TO_IMAGE'/>");
            currentStepList.prepend(imgMarker);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in php or html link yo nned to pass a step parameter into the URL, like so: `https://yourwebpage.com/blog/?step=1`

Hope this will be helpful to you.